# Auth0 unauthorized_client: Callback URL mismatch error in new React Native app

Tags: react-native, auth0

I've created a new React Native app that will use the same Auth0 database as my web app.

I created the app in Auth0 portal and created all the necessary settings following this article: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/react-native/00-login

Even though the callback URL is listed in Auth0 portal, after a log in attempt, I'm getting the following error:

> error = unauthorized_client: Callback URL mismatch.
> com.ingridtime://ingrid.auth0.com/android/com.ingridtime/callback
> is not in the list

Here's the actual callback list from the Auth0 portal:
[image]

I'm using the latest versions of both React Native and Auth0 packages. Here's a screen shot of my `package.json` dependencies section:

[image]

Any idea what the issue here is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The issue was with the custom login screen we had created which had another app's ID hard-coded in it.